# Microsoft phone application attaching a image in email

Tags: windows-phone-7, email, windows-phone

Is it possible to attach a image file in windows mobile phone application developed in 7.5? i have searched many websites but can't find any  solution . please help me if there is any.I have downloaded this code  http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/File-Upload-in-Silverlight-3.aspx  but ain't able to run. I faced a problem with silverlight convertion. They said i need to install some component which will match with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.
The only solution is either send the email using some dedicated web service you can create, or encode the image into Base64 and add it directly to the body of the email.
Sadly nothing has changed in this matter in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

Another route you can take, which may not apply to your situation as you don't provide much detail on what your app does, is to use the Live SDK. If you integrate your app into Skydrive you can send images and video via proxy (a SkyDrive link).

This is how I've approached the issue in my app Video Journal.